# How do you stop two concurrent processes?

Tags: bash, shell, concurrency, process

In my web development workflow, I have two processes:

1. watching my folder for changes
2. previewing my site in the browser

I want to be able to run them and then later stop them both at the same time. I've seen everyone suggesting using the ampersand operator:

```
process_1 & process_2
```

But pressing `Ctrl + C` only stops the second one. I have to `kill` the first one manually. What am I missing in this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the foreground script explicitly kill the subprocesses in response to SIGINT:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap 'kill $pid1 $pid2' 2
cmd1 &
pid1=$!
cmd2 &
pid2=$!
wait
```

There is a race condition in this example: if you send `SIGINT` to the parent before `pid1` is assigned, `kill` will emit a warning message and neither child will be terminated.  If you send `SIGINT` before `pid2` is assigned, only the process running `cmd1` will be sent the signal.  In either case, the parent will continue running and a second `SIGINT` can be sent.  Some versions of `kill` allow you to avoid this race condition by sending a signal to the process group using `kill -$$`, but not all versions of `kill` support that usage.  (Note that if either child process does not terminate in response to the signal, the parent will not exit but continue waiting.)

Answer (score 2):

How about writing two scripts, one containing

```
./process_1 &
./process_2 &
```

and a second containing

```
killall process_1
killall process_2
```

Start both prcesses by running the first script, and end them by running the second script.